# If halving signal strength is only a 3db drop, why can't cell phones be much lower powered?

Tags: power, signal-processing, microwaves

My phone can receive a signal that's -90dBm. That's roughly one-billionth of a milliwatt. Cutting a signal's strength in half only drops the signal by 3dBm. Apart from slightly higher range, is there a good reason that we don't have cell phones broadcasting at only, say, 50mw instead of 800? Is 12dBm really that much in terms of range? Given the inverse square law, it doesn't seem like it would get you all that much.

Comment: Is the basis of your question that 1/16th seems like a a big change, but -12 dB does not?

Comment: Not really. Given the scale of things, 1/16th seems like a negligible change.

Answer (score 5):

You do know that your phone will transmit only enough power to reach the nearest tower right? Most of the time that is much less than the max it is capable of. But when there are buildings between you and the tower or you are on the open road you'll be happy not to be dropping so many calls...

So there are two things to notice here. First - every 3 dB doubles the power, but the inverse square law tells you that you need four times the power to get twice as far: so 12 dBm additional power gets you 4x as far. 1 mile becomes 4 miles. In less densely populated areas, this means that cell towers can be spaced much further apart - you only need 1/16th of the number of cell towers, which are the biggest expense for the cellular carrier.

At the same time, in dense areas you actually want the towers closer together because you don't want interference from far away: so phones are configured to drop their transmit power until it's just enough to reach the tower they are communicating with - the tower and the phone actually exchange information about the quality of the signal received to reach the optimum transmit power. This allows a phone that is a few miles away to use the same channel as your phone, without interference. This is important to get high capacity in high density areas. It also saves battery life. Have you ever noticed your phone going "dead" faster when you are out in the country? This is why...

Cell phones need to be able to deal with both scenarios, so they have a high upper limit on their transmit power - but hardly ever use it. They would have terrible battery life if they did.